# Losing access token when the url doesn't contain #access_token=...(access_token)

Tags: javascript, spotify, access-token

So after logging in via Spotify OAUTH I have it redirecting to localhost:3000, and it puts the access token in the url like this

http://localhost:3000/#access_token=BQDqsegEs...

The access token properly being stored in local storage when I set it there when the URL contains the access token, but after I redirect to a different page, url of the access token will go away when I redirect like this:

```
this.props.history.push({
    pathname: '/playlist/'
});
```

http://localhost:3000/playlist

I also lose total access to the access token when the url didn't contain it. So when I navigate to different pages should I do:

```
this.props.history.push({
    pathname: '/playlist/#access_token=BQDq...'
});
```

This allows the transfer of the access token page to page, but it seems like an ugly way to go about it

Comment: it's better to keep the access token in the state or a variable

Comment: just did @EhsanNazeri

Comment: I thought localStorage was the best thing to use for an accessToken @EhsanNazeri

Comment: that's a good option but I think you should handle it at server side.

Comment: @EhsanNazeri so by server side you mean just passing it through a state variable in the constructor

Comment: what language do you use for back-end ?

Comment: @EhsanNazeri Its all client side front end for now, as spotify's API is doing all of the backend work for me, I'm just grabbing the user's music data from the API itself and displaying it, thats all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215482/discussion-between-ehsan-nazeri-and-surpol).